# grepl contain multi pattern at least one time in R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

**TARGET:** 
return elements with "TAX" and "GAP" at least one time ,without care of their position in string.

```
#STRING
K <- c("TAX","TAX GAP","GAP TAX","GAP of TAX","GAP") # 1st , 5th should be FALSE

#Solution
K[grepl("TAX",K) & grepl("GAP",K)]

# WRONG apporach
grepl("TAX|GAP",K)  --> Only one side
grepl("TAX+GAP+",K) --> The positions are fixed , impossible to write all the possibilities
```

**Can i write multi grepl() statment in one line with regex?**

Welcome for any other approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a single call to `grepl`, then we can try using the following single regex pattern:

```
\bTAX\b.*\bGAP\b|\bGAP\b.*\bTAX\b
```

This pattern uses an *alternation* to check for both orders in which `TAX` and `GAP` might occur.  Note also that `TAX` and `GAP` are surrounded by word boundary markers (`\b`) on each side, to make sure that we don't accidentally match e.g. `TAX` when it happens to occur in a substring of a larger word like `TAXES`.

```
grepl("\\bTAX\\b.*\\bGAP\\b|\\bGAP\\b.*\\bTAX\\b", K)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice approach . But i have to admit i posted a bad example which is a ENGLISH situation , actual case of mine dealing with the case like chinese character . "adjective" before "nouns " (<-- the target )without any \b  boundary , at same time they don't have worries of accidentally get pural (TAXES)  So , taking lesson on your answer .  grepl("X.*Z|X.*X",CHINESE) solve the problem . No doubt , the posted ans which able to avoid   "TAXES" is smart .